# How should I name importable .sqlite persistent store?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am creating CoreDataStack with pre importing .sqlite database file into my project.

```
 func seedCoreDataContainerIfFirstLaunch() {
    //1
    let previouslyLaunched = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "previouslyLaunched")
    if !previouslyLaunched {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "previouslyLaunched")
        // Default directory where the CoreDataStore will store its files.
        let directory = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()
        let url = directory.appendingPathComponent(modelName  + ".sqlite")

        //2: Copying the SQLite file
        let seedDatabaseURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: modelName , withExtension: "sqlite")!
        print(seedDatabaseURL)
        _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: seedDatabaseURL, to: url)

        } catch let nserror as NSError {
            fatalError("Error: \(nserror), \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
        }
        // 3: Copying the SHM file

        let seededSHMURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: modelName , withExtension: "sqlite-shm")!
        let shmURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(modelName + ".sqlite-shm")
        _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: shmURL)
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: seededSHMURL, to: shmURL)
        } catch let nserror as NSError {
            fatalError("Error: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
        }

  // 4: Copying the WAL file
        let seededWALURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: modelName  , withExtension: "sqlite-wal")
        let walURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(modelName  + ".sqlite-wal")

  _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: walURL)
  do {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: seededWALURL!, to: walURL)
  } catch let nserror as NSError {
    fatalError("Error: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
  }

  print("Seeded Core Data")
}
}
```

And i wondered do i have to name my persistent store same as a name of my xcdatamodeled file? If i must then how should i give a name for my secodpersistence store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A persistent store file can have any legal file name. Core Data has no rules about the file names.

`NSPersistentContainer` uses a default file name, but you can change that. Use its `persistentStoreDescriptions` property, which lets you specify a variety of details including the URL of the persistent store file.